# SubMenu / HTML Container not Scrolling on iPhone, but Does Scroll on All Other Devices

Tags: html, css, iphone, scrollview, overflow

I have a website mobile menu that when you select one of the menu items ('Practice Areas') it has a submenu with 11 list items. I have `overflow-y:scroll` set on both the parent and the submenu itself.

On small desktop window height sizes / Android devices the submenu does scroll as desired to show all of the items.

HOWEVER, when I look at it on an iPhone the submenu doesn't scroll. I do have the `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;` property set on both the parent and child elements

Due to the nature of the problem I can't upload it to CodePen etc because the screen view doesn't replicate a proper mobile viewing window. I have uploaded the problem here: [The Problem](https://inset.agency/ps14/)

Any solution to this would be so amazing. (You will need an iPhone to help with this obviously)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue by adding a height value (100%) to the submenu element so it worked in Safari